# How do I restrict images to container after scaling them?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have created a grid with 4 columns 2 rows. The grid has a width of the whole page and each section is split evenly. I want to have an image in each one scaled at 1.1 and when the user hovers over the image, the scale reverts back to 1. The problem I'm running into right now is that when I scale it at 1.1, the images seem to overlap each other and they're no longer contained to their section of the grid (see image below where I have hovered over the 2nd page 2.jpg).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <img id="pic1" src="1.jpg">
            <img id="pic2" src="2.jpg">
            <img id="pic3" src="3.jpg">
            <img id="pic4" src="4.jpg">
            <img id="pic5" src="5.jpg">
            <img id="pic6" src="6.jpg">
            <img id="pic7" src="7.jpg">
            <img id="pic8" src="8.jpg">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
    background-color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.container img:hover {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Screenshot shows what happens when I hover over 2nd picture 2.jpg. The problem is that right now with the scale applied, images 1,2,5,6 are all overlapping in their corners. They are not restricted to the size of the original grid created by the container.

Comment: This is how ``transform`` works, it changes the dimensions of the elements independently. You will always lose some image spaces there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by wrapping your images in containers and setting the `overflow` property of those containers to `hidden` (and the `width` to `100%`).

Like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="image-container">
                <img id="pic1" src="1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="image-container">
                <img id="pic2" src="2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="image-container">
                <img id="pic3" src="3.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="image-container">
                <img id="pic4" src="4.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="image-container">
                <img id="pic5" src="5.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="image-container">
                <img id="pic6" src="6.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="image-container">
                <img id="pic7" src="7.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="image-container">
                <img id="pic8" src="8.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
    background-color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.container .image-container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container .image-container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.container .image-container img:hover {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

Comment: thank you! It works. Just have 2 questions to clarify my understanding. 1. Is there a particular reason you use .container .image-container rather than just .image-container? 2. What was wrong with my code before? I understand that I didn't wrap the images in a container. However, wouldn't the image be fit into the size of the grid anyway?

Comment: Sure thing. 1: Just to be more specific, might be other `.image-container`s on the page and wouldn't necessarily want to mess with those, but not necessary. 2: Issue was that the size of the items in the grid was changing (with the `transform`), so that would override the `width` you set on them. Here the grid items (`.image-container`), stay the same size, but things inside of them (`img`) change size and any overflow gets clipped within the grid cell, rather than the entire grid (`.container`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do this, enclose them with a div with `overflow:hidden` and specify a certain `height` for those divs.

And instead of scaling the image via transform, you could increase its width to 110%.

Run demo below;

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container div {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  transition:0.4s;
}

.container img:hover {
  width: 110%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="">
      <img id="pic1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498837167922-ddd27525d352?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80">
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <img id="pic2" src="https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/different-types-of-food-on-rustic-wooden-table-picture-id861188910?s=612x612">
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <img id="pic3" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498837167922-ddd27525d352?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80">
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <img id="pic4" src="https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/different-types-of-food-on-rustic-wooden-table-picture-id861188910?s=612x612">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```